# How to build Rest Api for custom model with one to one relationship with django user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to build a rest api endpoint for create operation on a model which has a one to one relationship with a Users model which inherits from abstractuser.

This is the Users model

```py
class Users(AbstractUser):
    is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my Admin model

```py
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='admin')
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization
```

This is my serializer

```py
class UsersSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

This is my create api view

```py
class UserCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    This class defines the create behavior of our rest api.

    get:
    Return a list of all the existing users.

    post:
    Create a new user instance.
    """
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersSerializers

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new Book."""
        # serializer.save()
        instance = serializer.save()
        instance.set_password(instance.password)
        instance.save()
```

I want to also be able to serialize an instance of admin model and its field together with the Users model, I do not know how to go about this, but I want to be able to display Admin model fields alongside Users model field and save Admin model data alongside Users model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one more fields in `serializer` like below

```py
class UsersSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'organization')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

Now, in `perform_create` method, create an object for `Admin`

```py
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new Book."""
        # serializer.save()
        instance = serializer.save()
        instance.set_password(instance.password)
        instance.save()
        organization = serializer.validated_data.get('organization')
        Admin.objects.create(
           user=instance,
           organization=organization
        )
```

Comment: Ok thanks but how do I perform an API read operation on the 2 models together, if there's any way to do that

Comment: @A.Sasori you can use `serializerMethodField`